# Making a gantt type chart in excel using if statements

Tags: excel, date, if-statement

So I basically have to create a gantt type chart that automatically fills in the start and end month of the project. The problem I'm having is that I have a specific start and end date like, Start: 06/17/18 and End: 07/20/19.

My Chart is categorized by months and not specific dates, so for this example I would need it to populate the cells starting from June 2018 until July of 2019.

I'm having some problems because I made an if statement that looked at the month and populated the cells by month, however, it would then only fill in the june and july cells of 2018 and 2019 and would leave all the other cells in between blank. I then added another filter for it to also look at the year, except it didn't help because since my "if statement" looks for everything in between the 6th and 7th month, it doesn't populate the 8th, 9th and other months of the rest of 2018 and the beginning months of 2019.

Here is my if statement:

```
=IF(AND(MONTH(N$3)>=MONTH($I5),MONTH(N$3)<=MONTH($J5), YEAR(N$3)>=YEAR($I5),YEAR(N$3)<=YEAR($J5)),"")
```

Here is a snippet of the work:
[image: Gannt Chart]

Comment: I don't understand your statement, you check your `AND` conditions twice, do nothing with it. Have you got a screen shot of what you have now and what you're aiming to achieve?

Comment: Sorry, but how could I add a picture to the comment, I couldn't find directions in the help center?

Comment: edit your original post with a link to the photo, do not add clarifications to the comments.

Comment: Are you able to see the picture?

Comment: I then do conditional formatting to populate the cells in green based on the quotation marks in the if statement. So if everything is true, then populate cell in green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your month names are actually dates like `1/1/18`, you can custom format them to be `mmmm-yy` to give `January-18`, then you can use the following formula.

```
=IF(OR($I4>=N$3, $J4>=N$3), IF(OR($I4<O$3, $J4<O$3), "inc", "ex"), "ex")
```

Put this in `N4` then copy it to cover your range. It uses `OR` instead of `AND` to check whether either start or finish date is after or equal to the 1st of the month, likewise for less than the 1st of the next month.

The out put will give you `inc` for if that month is included in the dates and `ex` for if its excluded, so you can change either the formula or conditional formatting to colour.

This won't work on the very last column of data, so where you months end, eg `December-19` you will have to put `1/1/20` in either the next column heading, or hard coded in the formula where required.

**EDIT**

Modified the formula as I realised you're in column I and J, not A and B.

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK($I4)), IF(OR($I4>=N$3, $J4>=N$3), IF(OR($I4<O$3, $J4<O$3), "inc", "ex"), "ex"), IF(NOT(ISBLANK($J4)), IF(AND(O$3>$J4, $J4>=N$3), "inc", "ex"), "ex"))
```

Comment: Awesome, it mostly worked out! I modified the inc and ex in order for the conditional formatting to work. The only problem I'm having now is that for projects that don't have a start date, it highlights everything until the end date. So I was thinking of either inputting that the start date to be the same as the end date for those projects, or is there another way to make sure it doesn't highlight anything if there is no start date.

Comment: Check my edit, not at the computer to test it fully, but added a condition if the start date is missing only to check whether the end date falls into a certain month. If this helps please take a read of this http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Your original code worked better so I just went with that one. The second one wasn't following the logic correctly so in order for me to only display ones with the start and finish date, I deleted the end dates to those that only had end dates. Turns out that I don't need the one with only one date to display anyways. Thanks again!